# Java group list of maps by value and insert as grouped list

Tags: java, collections

Not sure if I am overcomplicating the requirement but this is what I need (for simplicity I will show a the `List<Map<String, Object>>` as a `JSON`):

```
[
    {
        "project": "Project1",
        "workType": "Dev",
        "taskTitle": "Dev Title 1",
        "effort": 150
    },
    {
        "project": "Project1",
        "workType": "Dev",
        "taskTitle": "Dev Title 2",
        "effort": 200
    },
    {
        "project": "Project1",
        "workType": "QA",
        "taskTitle": "QA Title 1",
        "effort": 50
    },
    {
        "project": "Project1",
        "workType": "QA",
        "taskTitle": "QA Title 2",
        "effort": 25
    },
    {
        "project": "Project2",
        "workType": "Dev",
        "taskTitle": "Dev Title 3",
        "effort": 300
    },
    {
        "project": "Project2",
        "workType": "Dev",
        "taskTitle": "Dev Title 4",
        "effort": 300
    },
    {
        "project": "Project2",
        "workType": "QA",
        "taskTitle": "QA Title 3",
        "effort": 125
    },
    {
        "project": "Project2",
        "workType": "QA",
        "taskTitle": "QA Title 4",
        "effort": 125
    }
]
```

I want to process a HashMap which is equivalent to the above to produce a HashMap equivalent to below:

```
[
    {
        "project": "Project1",
        "effort": 425, // sum of all efforts
        "types": [
            {
                "workType": "Dev",
                "effort": 350 // sum of all effort where workType == Dev
            },
            {
                "workType": "QA",
                "effort": 75 // sum of all effort where workType == QA
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "project": "Project2",
        "effort": 850, // sum of all efforts
        "types": [
            {
                "workType": "Dev",
                "effort": 600 // sum of all effort where workType == Dev
            },
            {
                "workType": "QA",
                "effort": 250 // sum of all effort where workType == QA
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the starting point of my attempt:

```
transformedData.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        m -> m.get("project"),
        Collectors.mapping( m2 -> m2, Collectors.toList() )
    )
);
```

Unfortunately I am a bit stuck on how to proceed..

UPDATE: The below gives me the expected result but it does not look performance friendly at all..

```
Map<Object, List<Map<String, Object>>> appGrouping = transformedData.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        m -> m.get("project"),
        Collectors.mapping(m2 -> m2, Collectors.toList())
    )
);

List<Map<String, Object>> finalData = new ArrayList<>();

appGrouping.forEach((k,v) -> {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("project", k);
    data.put("types", new ArrayList<>());
    v.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            m -> m.get("workType"),
            Collectors.summingDouble(m -> getDoubleVal(m.get("effort")))
        )
    ).forEach((k2,v2) -> {
        Map<String, Object> data2 = new HashMap<>();
        data2.put("workType", k2);
        data2.put("effort", v2);
        getFromMap(data, "types", List.class).add(data2); // this is a util method I wrote to get a value from a map
        Double totalEffort = Objects.requireNonNull(getFromMap(data, "effort", Double.class)) + v2;
        data.put("effort", totalEffort);
    });
    finalData.add(data);
});
```

Comment: It can be done.  But wouldn't it be better to have  a `Project` class and a `WorkType` class with getters for the fields?  Then you can have a `List<Project>` which, based on the above, would have two instances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. You are correct but the reason I did not map it to a POJO is because the method that does this should be sort of generic as in the group by keys (in this scenario its `project` and `workType` is parameterized) and I don't want to use reflection or anything like that yet.. However, if its simpler, it would be great if you could show me the way you would do it. Even if you use POJO's its fine. I'll do my best to translate it to my usecase

Comment: I will also post an update to the question soon with the current progress. Thanks for your time

Comment: You say *The below gives me 75% of the expected result* - What's in the missing 25%? And your question needs more focus; right now its goal is too broad/complex. Please edit your question to isolate the specific problem and the smallest amount of codein which the  problem exists. The context (json etc) of your question seems irrelevant to your problem, which cold be described using POJO's, thus simlifying the problem statement and the code. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Bohemian hi the missing part was I was not getting sum of the grouped effort at the project level but I updated the question. Now the attempt I have shown gives me the expected result.. I dont know how to optimize it :(

Comment: @Bohemian I showed the JSON because it will make it easier to visualize the problem I am having. Which is to group a List of Maps. I dont agree that the problem could be DESCRIBED using POJO since POJO is irrelevant to this question. However an answer could be given using POJO's which is fine

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "optimization"? eg Less code? Easier to read? Faster execution? Easier maintenance? Easier to test? Better style?

Comment: @Bohemian Faster execution is what I am hoping for. I am not all that knowledgeable on Java Streams and more particularly the `groupingBy` functionality. Thanks

Comment: @WJS Thanks for your effort, however if you read recent comments, OP *already* has it working. Now OP's focus has shifted to "optimization" - yet to be defined by OP - so I've asked OP to clarify and edit to bring more focus to the question.

Comment: @Bohemian  I found out streams was just to cumbersome (at least for me) But I did it in one pass using various `compute` constructs of map.  I'll save my results and follow the question for changes in its status.

Comment: @Bohemian by optimization I hope for faster execution as I have stated in my comment from 30 mins ago at the time of posting this comment. That being said I would like to see the logic implemented by WJS. I have implemented a working model, yes, but I have posted in the hope of someone improving it or posting a better way of doing it. Hope this changes your mind and you reopen the question. Thanks :D

Comment: @WJS thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Bohemian so when looking at the code I posted do you not feel that it could be improved? Be it performance wise or better coding practices etc.? I know I said I want more performant code but honestly at this point, whatever gets this question reopened :D

Comment: Please state what is the current run time complexity. Do you want a better solution in terms of run time complexity or in terms of milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get it in a single pass.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> tempMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();

transformedData.forEach(i -> {
    Double currentEffort = (Double) i.get("effort");
    
    Map<String, Object> subMap = 
            tempMap.computeIfAbsent((String)i.get("project"), 
                    (k) -> new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                        put("project", (String)i.get("project"));
                        put("effort", 0.0D);
                        put("types", new HashMap<String, Double>());}});
    
    subMap.merge("effort", currentEffort, (o, n) -> (Double)o + (Double)n);
    
    ((Map<String, Double>)subMap.get("types"))
        .merge((String) i.get("workType"), currentEffort, (o, n) -> (Double)o + (Double)n);
});
List<Map<String, Object>> finalData = (List<Map<String, Object>>) tempMap.values();
```

The finalData object converted to JSON (using your data above as input) is the below.  I've changed the types object from a list of maps to a map of workType to effort.

```
[
    {
        "types": {
            "QA": 250.0,
            "Dev": 600.0
        },
        "project": "Project2",
        "effort": 850.0
    },
    {
        "types": {
            "QA": 75.0,
            "Dev": 350.0
        },
        "project": "Project1",
        "effort": 425.0
    }
]
```